# UICollectionView unresponsive to swipe on the right w-h pixels in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UICollectionView` that I am populating with several cells and a custom flow layout. This works great in portrait mode. When I rotate to landscape I encounter an issue where I can't swipe up/down on the right portion of the screen. It seems to be the right w-h pixels which are unresponsive to touch. The collection view does draw cells properly and everything else seems normal. Also, if I begin a swipe in the working zone and go diagonally into the unresponsive area, the drag continues to work.

When the device is rotated, I make the following calls:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    _currentIndex = self.assetsCollectionView.contentOffset.y / self.assetsCollectionView.bounds.size.height;
    [self.assetsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    float y = _currentIndex * self.assetsCollectionView.bounds.size.height;
    [self.assetsCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:NO];
}
```

These look fine to me, and when I comment them out completely, I get the same behavior.

Other details: The UICollectionView is the only UI component in my View Controller, except for a small detail label which I'm sure is not the issue.

I'm switching between two subclasses of UICollectionViewFlowLayout so that the cells can expand to full screen and back, but I'm experiencing the same problem no matter which layout, or even before I swap them out. One more detail is that the fullscreen layout is pageEnabled while the smaller one is not.

The containing UIViewController is inside a UITabController.

One more note: I've double checked my layout constraints to ensure there isn't funny business there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. After spending an evening trying to figure out what was wrong I managed to solve it by adding these two lines in viewDidLoad method of the CollectionView view controller class. (I do not use autolayout)

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

I hope that this solves your issue too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up reconstructing the entire UIViewController from scratch which removed the problem. I never did find out what it was even though I was trying to isolate it as I reconstructed. I did notice this behavior in another screen though. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: @user3034156 solution worked for me. I was having the same problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me and saved me hours of debugging. Thank you!